# How to continuously monitor the Internet and updates my views in multiple screens

Tags: android

In some of the screens in my app I want to continuously monitor the internet connection and want to disable the buttons if the internet is not there and whenever internet is there i want to just enable that button.
        I have got the code which monitors the internet connection continuously but how to disable the button in multiple screens i am not getting.

> **NetworkStateReceiver.Java**

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
            NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"NOT-CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For monitoring network and Internet connection you can use [NetworkEvents](https://github.com/pwittchen/NetworkEvents) library, which I developed some time ago. It should meet your expectations. It uses BroadcastReceivers and Otto Event Bus under the hood. After properly registering and unregistering Bus and NetworkEvents. You can subscribe for your event in your activity like that:

```
@Subscribe
public void onConnectivityChanged(ConnectivityChanged event) {
   if(event.getConnectivityStatus() == ConnectivityStatus.WIFI_CONNECTED_HAS_INTERNET) {
      // enable your button
   } else if(event.getConnectivityStatus() == ConnectivityStatus.OFFLINE) {
     // disable your button
   }
}
```

You can also use status `MOBILE_CONNECTED`, when you want to perform specific action, when device is using mobile network.
For more details, [read documentation of the library](https://github.com/pwittchen/NetworkEvents/blob/master/README.md).

Another solution can be RxJava and RxAndroid, but in that case, probably you will have to handle Internet connection check by yourself. You can read about RxAndroid here: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/.

**EDIT**:

I've created another project, which solves the same problem, but this time with RxJava and Reactive Programming approach. It's a successor of NetworkEvents library. It's called ReactiveNetwork and can be found at: https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork. On the website of the repository you can find [examples of usage](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork#usage) and [sample app](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork#examples).

Comment: I’ve tried using the RxAndroid one but I couldn’t get it to work. I raised a question on it. Could you take a look?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098430/how-to-observe-network-changes-in-rxandroid

Comment: I'm not sure if such functionality is available in official RxAndroid library now and if it's stable and tested. I'll take a look on it later, when I find some time.