# How to observe network changes in RxAndroid

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I’m using the code given [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/128).

I put those code blocks as classes in my project’s util package. And then in the main activity class I wrote this..

```
class MenuActivity {

// Variable declaration
  private final CompositeSubscription mConnectionSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Some initialisation of UI elements done here

    mConnectionSubscription.add(AppObservable.bindActivity(this, NetworkUtils.observe(this)).subscribe(new Action1<NetworkUtils.State>() {
        @Override
        public void call(NetworkUtils.State state) {
            if(state == NetworkUtils.State.NOT_CONNECTED)
                Timber.i("Connection lost");
            else
                Timber.i("Connected");
        }
    }));

}
```

My goal is to monitor the changes and change a variable MyApp.isConnected defined in the MyApp class statically whenever the network changes to true false. Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What's the problem? Are the logs not showing up?

Comment: Yes they were not showing up. I switched to toast messages and tried it on a real device; it worked. I guess it had something to do with the emulator. The issue is resolved so I’m glad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use **[rxnetwork-android](https://github.com/Laimiux/rxnetwork-android)**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Subscription sendStateSubscription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Observable<RxNetwork.State> sendStateStream =
                RxNetwork.stream(this);

        sendStateSubscription = AppObservable.bindActivity(
                this, sendStateStream
        ).subscribe(new Action1<RxNetwork.State>() {
            @Override public void call(RxNetwork.State state) {
                if(state == RxNetwork.State.NOT_CONNECTED)
                    Timber.i("Connection lost");
                else
                    Timber.i("Connected");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        sendStateSubscription.unsubscribe();
        sendStateSubscription = null;

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You asked me for an answer in another thread. I'm answering late, because I needed some time to develop and test solution, which I find good enough.

I've recently created new project called [ReactiveNetwork](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork).

It's open-source and available at: https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork.

You can add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:x.y.z'
}
```

Then, you can replace `x.y.z` with the latest version number.

After that, you can use library in the following way:

```
 ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(context)        
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<ConnectivityStatus>() {
      @Override public void call(Connectivity connectivity) {
        if(connectivity.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
          Timber.i("Connection lost");
        } else if(connectivity.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
          Timber.i("Connected");
        }
      }
    });
```

You can also use `filter(...)` method from RxJava if you want to react only on a single type of event.

You can create a subscription in `onResume()` method and then unsubscribe it in `onPause()` method inside Activity.

You can find more examples of usage and sample app on the website of the project on GitHub.

Moreover, you can read about [NetworkInfo.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html) enum from Android API, which is now used by the library.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had already resolved the issue in my earlier project from Alex's answer. This should be of great use in future projects.